# return back to latest opened activity and update it

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity, return, updating

is there any way to return back to latest opened activity and update it
I use this code to return back :

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

but I want to update it, for example adding new elements dynamicaly
I saw the log but I think it doesn't run theoncreate method
then how can I update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can achieve this.if you are opening one activity from another activity and updating some elements,and if you need to update that in your previous activity based on the result then open your intent for result..

Example will be

```
    Intent abc = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    startActivityForResult(abc,123);
```

that will open your B.class..while that class completes its operation call

```
      setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

and after that in your A.class

override this function

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==123&& resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    //do something...... /*This is the code for updating your A.class */
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, honestly, I don't test it until now, I try to use onResume because I have found that it is called when the activity is in front

Comment: just test it but it the class B doesn't launch class A when I call setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_datat)